# Why the command button close my dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, commandbutton

I work on primefaces 6.0 and I have a dialog box, called by a command button, I have several element in this dialog box and 2 command button, one is for closing the dialog box, the other (commandButton id="enableDisableButton") is an option of my program. It must display True or False, like a select boolean button. But when I click on the button, it close my dialog box and I don't understand why !

```html
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="rulesDialogBox" modal="true" 
                    width="540" height="400" minWidth="540" minHeight="400"
                    dynamic="true">

    <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="border:none !important;">
        <h:outputText id="selectedFile" value="#{eventConfigurationView.loadedFile}"/>

        <p:fileUpload label="#{msgs.rule_browse}" fileUploadListener="#{eventConfigurationView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" 
                      update="selectedFile" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls)$/"
                      minHeight="30px" minWidth="110px"
                      style="margin-bottom:20px;" />
                      <!-- allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|csv|xlsx)$/" -->

        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.download}" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" style="margin:5px;" 
                            minHeight="30px" minWidth="110px">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{eventConfigurationView.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton id="enableDisableButton" 
                            value="#{eventConfigurationView.myEnable}" style="margin:5px;" 
                            action="#{eventConfigurationView.buttonAction}"
                            ajax="false"
                            minHeight="30px" minWidth="110px">
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.close}" onclick="PF('rulesDialogBox').hide();" type="button" style="margin:5px;" 
                            minHeight="30px" minWidth="110px"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

```java
    public void buttonAction() {
        System.out.println("buttonAction");
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you refer to `p:commandButton id="enableDisableButton"` you have disabled ajax on it via `ajax="false"`.
This reloads the entire page on click. As the initial state of the `p:dialog` is hidden, it looks like the dialog disappers while in fact the page has reloaded completely.